# Where and how do I store my GitHub branches on my local system?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, branch, git-bash

I have been learning about GitHub branches and have been stumped after multiple Stack overflow, Google, and YouTube searches I am more confused. I began having trouble when a branch is created on a repo, I know how to access or change it to the branch on Git Bash, but if I wanted to clone the main branch and work under the new branch on my system what does that look like? Simply stated if I clone my website's main branch which I have stored on my local drive in folder my-website where would I store my branch code? Do I have it in another separate folder inside that folder or outside of it? What is the best practices or habits when dealing with issues like this? Thank you and sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Branches are not much more than pointers that can be moved around, so creating a new branch is more like creating a pointer, and no code gets copied (so "cloning" isn't the right term here). [This chapter in the *Pro Git* book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) is an excellent intro to Git branching.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a branch like a label. Each version of your code is defined as a blob, and each branch can be assigned as a sort of "label" for a specific blob of your choice. So, you can easily reference a blob by using the name of the branch you created.

The term "branch" can be misleading in this way because it does not refer to the branching of the overall version tree.

In short, just create new branches when you want new reference points.